# How to find what products sell well with others in an SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of sales

```
SALE_ID   |   Product_Code    |  Qty   |  Sales_Value  | Taxes ....
==========+===================+========+===============+=========
001       |   AAAA            |   1    |  1000         | 50     ....
001       |   BBBB            |   1    |  10           | 0.5
002       |   CCCC            |   1    |  30           | 1.5
002       |   AAAA            |   1    |  1000         | 1.5
```

I'm trying to get a table which shows how many times one product is sold with another with a same sales id (sold on the same invoice)

```
Product ID  |  Product ID 2   |  Sales Together
============+=================+==================
AAAA        |  BBBB           |      1
AAAA        |  CCCC           |      1
BBBB        |  AAAA           |      1
BBBB        |  CCCC           |      0
CCCC        |  AAAA           |      1
CCCC        |  BBBB           |      0
```

I'm using MS SQL, I think I have to do a group query where I group by the sale, and then product Id but thats where I get confused on how to cross count sales together.

If it is convenient I also have a table of product masters

```
Product_ID   |  Description    |
=============+=================|
AAAA         | Battery         |
BBBB         | Flashlight      |
CCCC         | Radio           |
```

Comment: Do you really need the results for `AAAA` and `BBBB` shown twice both ways round? Do you have another table that contains productIds? If so how many rows does that have and how many rows are there in the Sales table?

Comment: I don't really need it but I thought it would be more convenient to display because it would need an additional query to remove the duplicates?

Comment: Yes I also have a Product "master" table with the product ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
SELECT P1.Product_Code,
       P2.Product_Code,
       Count(DISTINCT S1.SALE_ID)
FROM   Product P1
       JOIN Product P2
         ON P1.Product_Code > P2.Product_Code
       LEFT JOIN Sales S1
                 INNER JOIN Sales S2
                   ON S1.SALE_ID = S2.SALE_ID
         ON S1.Product_Code = P1.Product_Code
            AND S2.Product_Code = P2.Product_Code
GROUP  BY P1.Product_Code,
          P2.Product_Code
```

Comment: is there a way I can modify It so I can count how many sales there were with a product (whether or not it was with another) too?