# Count product-pairs that have been purchased by same customer

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table of customer-product entries for each product a customer has purchased

```
cust, prod
A,1
A,3
B,1
B,2
B,3
```

And I want to eventually create a product matrix that has the number of customers that purchased product pairs

```
   1, 2, 3
1, -, 1, 2
2, 1, -, 1
3, 2, 1, -
```

So, my question is how can I take the 1st table and transform it into something like

```
prod1, prod2, count
1, 2, 1
1, 3, 2
2, 1, 1
2, 3, 1
3, 1, 2
3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this question answered here:

[How to find what products sell well with others in an SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894825/how-to-find-what-products-sell-well-with-others-in-an-sql-server-query)

Instead of taking the **sale_id**, you'll be using the **customer**